# Contracts / Releases For Website ( Amateur ) Models

Tags: legal, web, models, model-releases

I've built a website which focuses on a Alternative culture, and I've just set up a section which looks at Alternative Modelling, as I've had quite a bit of interest from models who would like to send me a few photos to publish on the website. I'd obvioulsly like to do this properly, and as some of the models who are interested in posting are very amateur, I'd prefer that when they sent me their photo's, they also sent me a little attached document stating that they permit me to use the photos and that they are over 18, and that I am able to use the photos 100% freely on the website.

Does anyone have any knowledge of this sort of thing, and know how to write up a proper document that will cover me and my website for the photos that are submitted.

This is only a small hobby website and not a major business, so I really don't want any suggestions about hiring expensive legal services to create high priced legal documents, I just want something that will cover the basics.

Thank you

Comment: We have some questions here about licensing, but this one is from the side of using photographs that already exist as a consumer — not the photography side. It might be better on http://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would just change " I am able to use the photos 100% freely" adding "for non comercial usage. If something becames comercial I will share the cake". That is just fair.

Comment: Well @Rafael, when it says "on the website", I do really mean on the website, as I don't plan on using any of the photos sent to me available for direct purchase. That being said, I do plan on making some photos available as part of an E-Book or Printable Magazine! However I would personally speak to the models who I would like to feature before such a publication is made, and make any nessessary payments if they agree - Therefore making this part of a seperate agreement/contract.

Comment: I would rely on what already exists and have a look at e.g. pages:

https://www.gettyimages.com/

https://500px.com/

https://www.shutterstock.com

https://www.flickr.com/

They have different kinds of licences you can read and you will see what they are expected from those who are positing photos.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look at iStocks Model Release.
That's how a contract is written to allow usage.

[iStock MR](http://www.istockphoto.com/docs/languages/english/modelrelease.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I'd also suggest that you countersign the model release and pass a copy back to the model for their reference. People often forget they signed something and sometimes try to shift the goal posts.

Also useful, if in the future you wish to do something else with the images outside of the original contract, you can then send them the original copy with any marked up new requirements for them to sign.